# "Launch path not accessible" using NSTask to create Git commit

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstask

I am trying to use `NSTask` to create a Git commit and to add a message to that commit.

This is the code I have tried.

```
NSString *projectPath = @"file:///Users/MYNAME/Desktop/MYPROJECT/";
//stage files
NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
task.launchPath = projectPath;
task.arguments = @[@"git", @"add", @"."];
task.standardOutput = pipe;
[task launch];

//commit
NSPipe *pipe2 = [NSPipe pipe];
NSTask *task2 = [[NSTask alloc] init];
task2.launchPath = projectPath;
task2.arguments = @[@"git", @"commit", @"-m",@"\"Some Message\""];
task2.standardOutput = pipe2;
[task2 launch];
```

I received `projectPath` by using `NSOpenPanel` (standard OS X open dialog).

In the Xcode terminal, I get the message 
"launch path not accessible"

So what am I doing wrong?

**Update**
After comment from Josh Caswell this is my code

```
NSString *projectPath = @"file:///Users/MYNAME/Desktop/MYPROJECT/";
NSString *gitPath = @"/usr/local/bin/git"; //location of the GIT on my mac

//stage
NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
task.launchPath = gitPath;
task.currentDirectoryPath = projectPath;
task.arguments = @[@"add", @"."];
task.standardOutput = pipe;
[task launch];
```

After [task launch]; I get error message in terminal "working directory doesn't exist."

Comment: The real answer for those with app sandboxing enabled https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018354/remove-sandboxing

Comment: The real answer for those with app sandboxing enabled https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018354/remove-sandboxing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task's [`launchPath`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nstask/1414221-launchpath?language=objc) is the path to *the program* you want to run: that's Git here, so that path probably needs to be `/usr/local/bin/git`. And remove `@"git"` from the arguments; it's not an argument, it's the executable.

The path to your project should be used for the task's [`currentDirectoryPath`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nstask/1413110-currentdirectorypath?language=objc) so that it has the correct working directory.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. What you said makes sense. Unfortunately I am still having no luck with this. When I type in Terminal: "which git" i get "/usr/bin/git" so I guess I should use this instead of "/usr/local/bin/git" for the launchPath. But still I get "launch path not accessible" error. Also when I add "currentDirectoryPath" I get message "launch path not accessible". Is there any way I can see what is being written to the prompt and in which folder? In order to debug this?

Comment: I don't think there is any output, because the `NSTask` itself isn't getting started. It sounds like there's a permissions or `$PATH` problem, but I can't imagine that /usr/bin isn't in the `$PATH`.

Comment: In Termainal I can call git from any folder. Also when I type "echo $PATH" i get "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Answer (score 1):

With the pointers from Josh Casswell's answer I managed to figure it out. I found out that I have to remove the `file://` part from the projectPath. So project path should be `@"/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/MYPROJECT/"`.

Also it should not contain spaces because it does not work with `%20` escape character. Which is kind of strange because when you use NSOpenPanel you get NSURL and when you call absolute path on it you get the `"file://"` at the start and `"%20"` instead of spaces inside of the path.

TLDR;
This code works in Xcode 8:

```
NSString *projectPath = @"/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/MYPROJECT/"; //be careful that it does not contain %20
NSString *gitPath = @"/usr/local/bin/git";
NSString *message = @"this is commit message";

//stage
NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
task.launchPath = gitPath;
task.currentDirectoryPath = projectPath;
task.arguments = @[@"add", @"."];
task.standardOutput = pipe;
[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];

//commit
NSPipe *pipe2 = [NSPipe pipe];
NSTask *task2 = [[NSTask alloc] init];
task2.launchPath = gitPath;
task2.currentDirectoryPath = projectPath;
task2.arguments = @[@"commit", @"-m", message];
task2.standardOutput = pipe2;
[task2 launch];
[task2 waitUntilExit];
```

**Update** 
Add [task waitUntilExit];
if you keep getting the message

> fatal: Unable to create
>   '/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/MYPROJECT/.git/index.lock': File exists.
>
> Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g. an
>   editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes are
>   terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process may have
>   crashed in this repository earlier: remove the file manually to
>   continue.

Comment: Glad you figured it out; feel free to award the checkmark to your own answer, since it seems to be more complete than mine.

Comment: As for the path, you probably want to use `-[NSURL path]` rather than `absolutePath`. You'll notice that the spaces are unescaped, and the scheme (`file://`) is not included.