# Very simple macOS XPC

Tags: swift, macos, sandbox, xpc

I want to use the [XPC](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html) technology simply to launch an `app`. I do not need any interprocess communication, or any of the other feature of XPC.

The only documents that I can find on the internet show a complex structure, with code for the XPC service, separate code to launch the XPC service via a script, and app code to communicate with the service.

In other words, I only want something that does the equivalent of this:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.openApplication(at: path,
                                   configuration: configuration,
                                   completionHandler: nil)
```

but with XPC. So I would need something along the lines of:

```
let listener = NSXPCListener.service("/path/to/my_app.app")
listener.resume()
RunLoop.main.run()
```

Obviously, the service method does not take an argument that would be an executable path, so this does not work.

How can I do that ?

PS: to explain the motivation, launching an XPC service will preserve sandbox restriction form the launching app, whereas launching the app directly via `NSWorkspace.shared.openApplication` will not preserve sandbox restrictions (because the spawned app does not have "com.apple.security.inherit" as entitlement).

Comment: The documentation for [NSTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstask) says "In a sandboxed application, child processes created with the NSTask class inherit the sandbox of the parent app". Does that achieve what you want more simply?

Comment: Thanks @TheNextman, it's a great idea. I just tried. Only problem now is that the sandboxed launcher app refuses to run the third party app. This third party app is signed with a different codesign (since it came from the app store), so that might be the issue... Not sure.

Comment: I managed to make it work, but very unfortunately, the launched app is actually still not sandboxed. I tried with Safari for example, and I can still browse the internet...

Comment: What is the app you are trying to launch? Is it sandboxed? What are its entitlements?

Comment: I tried with a few different things. I built an empty app, and tried different entitlements. For example, only the Sandbox  entitlement. I’ve also tried with Safari.

Comment: Did you read "Enabling App Sandbox Inheritance" on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html)? "To enable sandbox inheritance, a child target must use exactly two App Sandbox entitlement keys: com.apple.security.app-sandbox and com.apple.security.inherit. If you specify any other App Sandbox entitlement, the system aborts the child process. You can, however, confer other capabilities to a child process by way of iCloud and notification entitlements."

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes I just read that actually. I think that means I cannot launch any app that do not have exactly these 2 entitlements, and therefore I can’t launch appstore apps... do you have any idea for a work around ?

Comment: The question feels like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to achieve? You just want to launch a Mac App Store app programmatically?

Comment: My goal is to launch a third party app from the appstore, in a sandbox. That way, it can’t use tracker or perform activities that I have no need for. It’s basically the function of the deprecated “sandbox-exec”

Comment: Right, but an App Store app is already sandboxed. So you are trying to override the entitlements it has? I know `sandbox-exec` is deprecated, but does it do what you want?

Comment: Yes, the app from the app store is already sandboxed, but has permissions too wide. So I want to start it in an encompassing sandbox to restrict it further. sandbox-exec does not work unfortunately on catalina.

Comment: `sandbox-exec` *does* work on Catalina; I just tried it. But I don't think it allows you to override the sandbox of an already sandboxed app. I'm happy to be proven wrong, but I don't think what you want to achieve is possible.

Comment: Ah really ? On my end, this command fails : "sandbox-exec -f sandbox_profile.sb /Applications/Safari.app"

Comment: Ah actually, sandbox-exec works for non sandboxed app. That's probably what you meant. It does not work with Safari because Safari is already sandbox. I don't know if there's a way to "increase" the sandbox restrictions of a third party app...

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Safari is already sandboxed: 'codesign -d --entitlements :- /Applications/Safari.app | grep -i "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" -A 1'

Comment: Yep, you're right. I'm a bit short of ideas at that point... It feels though that it should be doable, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: The protections are probably just to prevent you from altering the sandboxing restrictions, full-stop. All I can think is that you can modify the target to remove the sandboxing entitlement, re-code sign it using an ad hoc identity, and then run it using sandbox-exec (or NSTask, etc)

Comment: That sounds like a great option, but is that possible? Can I really remove entitlements of a third party app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018354/remove-sandboxing

Comment: Thanks a lot! That looks very promising, I'll look into that.

Comment: Amazing, that worked ! Thanks a lot @TheNextman! You definitely deserved some points on this, so I upvoted some other responses you made, since you didn't have a response on my question.

Comment: can you answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69297472/simplest-client-server-example-code-using-ipc-using-xpc-using-swift-on-macos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem possible to launch a sub process while altering it's sandbox (i.e. giving it more or less entitlements than it was originally blessed with).

I recommend [stripping the sandboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018354/remove-sandboxing) from the existing application, modifying the entitlements appropriately and then re-signing it. It's not a regular approach but would solve your specific issue.