# Appkit: How to perform an NSMetadataQuery on a Local Folder

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

I'm trying to perform an `NSMetadataQuery` on a **local macOS Folder** (not in iCloud) using Appkit like this:

```
    let query = NSMetadataQuery()
    query.valueListAttributes = [ NSMetadataItemURLKey ]
    //Set the App's Documents folder as the SearchScope
    query.searchScopes = [FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!]
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleQueryNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGathering, object: query)
    query.enableUpdates()
    query.start()
```

However, I never get a notification that the query finished gathering results. When I change the searchScope to `[NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]`, I do get a notification.

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmetadataquery/1412155-searchscopes) it seems that this should be possible:

> This array can contain NSURL or NSString objects that represent file-system directories or the search scopes for the query

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't indicate what you're looking for, but before calling query.start, you first have to set query.predicate

(per doc:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmetadataquery)

for example:

```
        query.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K LIKE '*.txt'", argumentArray: [NSMetadataItemFSNameKey])
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Now I do get a result back, but it's always an empty array, even when I stocked the folder with soms .txt files.

Comment: I have tried different nspredicates, but I keep getting an empty array back so maybe there is still another problem left.

Comment: Here's the file I was playing with, in case it might help in isolation: https://gist.github.com/dldnh/819f11633359222bcf361a8da6e38a06

Comment: Your app uses a separate set of directories when it is sandboxed. In case you're looking to access the user's `~/Documents` directory instead, make sure to follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59752583