# While loop with NSFileManager directory enumerator not running

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, while-loop, nsfilemanager

I am seeking help to understand why [a tutorial I am following](https://github.com/lucasderraugh/AppleProg-Cocoa-Tutorials/tree/master/Lesson%2051) is not working for me. I am running macOS 12.3.1, Xcode 13.3.1. The project is in Objective-C and using XIB.
This is a view-based NSTableView, using a folder of PNGs stored on my SSD for the `imageView` and the `stringByDeletingPathExtension` as `stringValue` for the cell's text field. I filled my code with `NSLog` calls to try and catch what could have been going awry.
Most setup is happening in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, where I initialise an `NSMutableArray` for the table's content, an `NSString` for the file path, then set up the file manager and the directory enumerator with said path (note: all working up to here).
Now comes the loop to populate the table contents' mutable array. I cannot understand why said loop gets skipped entirely! Its condition is to set an `NSString` equal to the `nextObject` of the directory enumerator. I am sure the loop gets skipped because the `NSLog` call after the loop runs!
Here is the entire code of `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, including my comments and logs (I have just replaced my account name with ):

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    _tableContents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *path = @"/Users/<myUsername>/Developer/Apple-Programming-YT/Cocoa Programming/Flags/PNG/40x30";
    
    // MARK: Debug 1
    NSLog(@"path found: %@", path); // the correct path gets printed, as expected
    
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *directoryEnum = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:path];
    
    NSString *file;

    // MARK: Debug 2
    NSLog(@"Checking that file is empty: %@", file); // (null) gets printed, as expected
    
    // MARK: Debug 3
    if (file != directoryEnum.nextObject) {
        NSLog(@"File cannot be assigned to the Directory Enumerator");
    } else if (file == directoryEnum.nextObject) {
        NSLog(@"File properly assigned. Proceed!"); // this gets printed! Is it correct?
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Something went wrong during assignment of nextObject to file");
    }
    
    while (file = [directoryEnum nextObject]) {
        NSLog(@"While loop entered!"); // this doesn't get printed! Why?!
        
        // MARK: Debug 4
        NSLog(@"File: %@", file);
        NSString *filePath = [path stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@", file];
        
        // MARK: Debug 5
        NSLog(@"Image filepath: %@", filePath);
        NSDictionary *obj = @{@"image": [[NSImage alloc] initByReferencingFile:filePath],
                              @"name": [file stringByDeletingPathExtension]};
        [self.tableContents addObject:obj];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"Table View Reloaded"); // This gets printed!
}
```

I have [uploaded the full app to GitHub](https://github.com/Cellomaster87/Apple-Programming-YT/tree/main/Cocoa%20Programming/Cocoa%20Pr%20L51%20ViewBased%20NSTableView), in case you may want to look at it and see if something else could be wrong, but every outlet, delegate, data source is connected.
Now for my diagnosis & ideas:

1. The Debug 3 mark is what I find most interesting. AFAIK `file` should still be `(null)`, so how checking if it is equal to `directoryEnum.nextObject` returns `YES`?
2. I created Debug 3 because the `NSLog` checking whether the loop had been entered didn't get printed. I therefore assumed the condition for the `while` loop had a problem.
3. I then tried to create a `do-while` loop instead of this `while` loop and, of course, the code ran. For the log with "Image filepath" it returned the address above followed by `(null)`, as if it didn't find the file. But how is it possible if the file is indeed there? Do I require some sort of permission to access it? Being the object empty, the next line in the console was quite clear: "attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]".
   But now, how do I solve this?

Any help here is much appreciated. If you download it from GitHub, please replaces the `*path` string with a folder of PNGs on your SSD.
Thank you.

Comment: Tip: [Remove Sandboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018354/remove-sandboxing).

Comment: Bravo @Willeke! That was it! Can you put this into an answer so that I can give it the accepted checkmark? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access the filesystem directly with a path like that any more. If you check the value of `file` in your code, it is nil, which means that `file == directoryEnum.nextObject` will evaluate to true.

You have to create a path starting with `NSHomeDirectory()` or similar and add components to it. This makes a path that goes via your application support folder, which contains an alias to the desktop. I'm not sure why that's OK and accessing it directly is not, but I'm not a Mac developer.

I'd have to say following a tutorial as old as that, you're going to struggle with a lot of things.

Comment: @willeke the `==` is copied from the question, I'm not sure what you mean