# Permission error occurs when I use setDefaultApplication(at:toOpen:completion:) in Swift

Tags: swift, macos

I'd like to set my macOS app written in Swift as default app when opening .mp4 file.
I think I can do it with setDefaultApplication(at:toOpen:completion:).
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/3753002-setdefaultapplication

However, permission error occurs when I use it.
The error is:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x6000031d0150 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "permErr: permissions error (on file open)"}}

I tried to give my app full-disk access, but it didn't work.
I also tried to use `setDefaultApplication(at:toOpenFileAt:completion:)`, then it works with no error, but it effects on only one file.

What I want to do is to set my app as default app of all .mp4 files.
How do I achieve this?

My code is like below:

```
let bundleUrl = Bundle.main.bundleURL
NSWorkspace.shared.setDefaultApplication(at: bundleUrl, toOpen: .mpeg4Movie) { error in
    print(error)
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

This API cannot be used in a sandboxed app. So, disabling sandbox should resolve the issue (how to disable see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018354/remove-sandboxing)). It seems there is no way of having the app sandboxed and changing the default application for a file type – there is no special entitlement to request or anything like that. But it also seems having an app not sandboxed is not too bad either.